# Lua Table Not Visible from API to Main Program

Tags: lua, scope, lua-table

This code is a function in an api called "marik" that I created with my own functions. I called the function with `marik.pLoad()` in the main program. The code works if used in the main program, so the code itself isn't an issue. Once I moved it to the API (which is loaded with lots of other functions that I use) then called the function, the main program doesn't know about `machines{}`. It's not local, so I don't know why it isn't visible.

API code:

```
function pLoad()
machines = peripheral.getNames() -- load a list of peripherals into a table
table.sort(machines) -- so it displays in non-random manner
end
```

Main program code:

```
marik.pLoad()
for i=1, #machines do
-- the rest is omitted
```

Error: attempt to get length of nil from this line:

```
for i=1, #machines do
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Attempt to get length of nil from for i=1, #machines do (works if the api function is in the main program).

Comment: I'm afraid I've never heard of `marik` before. Is there any documentation?

Comment: It's my own API with my functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what's going on now. I assume you have two files, something like this.

#### marik.lua

```
module(..., package.seeall)

function pLoad()
    machines = peripheral.getNames() -- load a list of peripherals into a table
    table.sort(machines) -- so it displays in non-random manner
end
```

#### main.lua

```
require'marik'

marik.pLoad()
for i=1, #machines do -- error here
```

---

So the problem is that because `marik` is in a module, it won't be accessing your `main` globals table. Instead, it will be accessing its own globals table, which happens to be `marik`. You will likely find `machines` under `marik.machines`.

One way you could fix this is by using a different module pattern, such as this.

#### marik.lua

```
local M = {}

function M.pLoad()
    -- ...
end

return M
```

#### main.lua

```
local marik = require'marik'

-- ...
```

---

If you read around, you'll soon find out that there's [at least a couple ways](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued) to make modules in Lua.